# Flutter - Problem combination of SchedulerBinding, showDialoag, AlertDialog and WillPopScope

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have an AlertDialog that appears immediatly when a go to new screen. It has BACK and GO button. I need to remain in this screen when I dismiss the AlertDialog only if the user press GO. If the user press BACK button or BACK Android Button I need to go to previous screen and not remain in the current screen.
When I dismiss AlertDialog I use Navigator.pop(context, false) in case of OK and Navigator.pop(context, true) in case of BACK using the bool returning type for second Navigator.pop(context) if this is true to going to previous screen.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) => _showDialog().then((isScreenToPop) {
     //ERROR: Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
        if (isScreenToPop) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        } else {
          setState(() {});
        }
      }),
    );
  }
```

Now I need to detect tap on BACK Android Button. For that I use WillPopScope with Future.value(true) but this returning null and the evaluation to use second Navigator.pop(context) returning Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null.

```
  Future<bool> _showADialog() {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (_) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            //THIS RETURN NULL AND NOT Future<true>
            return Future.value(true);
          },
          child: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, setState) {
              return AlertDialog(
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('BACK'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop<bool>(context, true);
                    },
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('OK'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop<bool>(context, false);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Temporary solution for now is the below but I don't like.

```
        if (isScreenToPop == null || isScreenToPop) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        } else {
          setState(() {});
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

just return `true` and not `Future.value(true)`. When you use `async` the return value will be automatically returned as a `Future`.

Also, if you need to `pop` multiple times, take a look at the other `pop` functions such as `popUntil`.

Comment: Same assertion null problem with:
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return true;
          },

Comment: Do a Hot Restart.

Comment: I don't think `onWillPop` will return a value to the  `showDialog` caller, try calling `pop(context, true)` there so you can return something.